# VirtualBox Windows 7 guest mouse only moves when the mouse is down

Tags: virtualbox, mouse-cursor

I am running a VirtualBox virtual Windows 7 machine and I have a problem.

when I move my mouse, it doesn't hover over anything in the virtual OS. it's only when I click does the mouse move to the spot.

without mouse integration it works as expected.

Comment: So with the Integration services enabled, you have to click inside the VM window before it will record your mouse position inside the VM? Does this include moving from one place INSIDE the VM to another place still INSIDE the VM? Or does it only occur when moving from OUTSIDE the VM to INSIDE the VM?

Comment: you're confusing me let me explain. the virtual mouse cursor INSIDE the virtual machine wasn't moving but my real mouse cursor looked like it and was. when I clicked the virtual cursor moved instantly to my mouse and clicked like normal, and drag worked too.